# Symfony2 app.user in twig

Tags: php, symfony

Whene displayin the app.user object like this in Twig

```
{{ dump(app.user) }}
```

I got all information about the current user

- the username
- the password
- the salt
- ...

How can I configure Symfony for storing only the **username** for example in the Session.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want it? That you can retrieve the salt from an object doesn't mean it is stored in the Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plugin your own UserInterface class (perhaps by overriding the existing Symfony class and then adjust the eraseCredientials() method to null out the password and the salt if you want.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

You can even go further and add __sleep and __wakeup methods (http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep) to control exactly which member variables end up in the session.

Answer (score 2):

`app.user` returns what is stored in the security token to identify your user. Probably, you will not want to change that. However, you can, for example, [create a custom Twig function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) which only returns the username if you want to have an easier way to access that value.